# angular $http service singleton clash

Tags: ajax, angularjs

$http service in angular is singleton, and my previous experience with xhr/ ajax request shown to have clash when two request share the same xhr object. Should it not a problem with angular ? if yes how angular handles such situation ?

Comment: post the code then only can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding the fact that the `$http` service is a singleton to mean that all requests somehow will share the same `XHR` object. They don't.

The `$http` service itself is a singleton, but that doesn't mean that the requests share the same `XHR` object.

Anytime you call an `$http` service method (for example, `$http#get`), it initializes a new asynchronous request... However, it doesn't initialize a new `$http` object.

Take a look at some of [Addy Osmani's](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#singletonpatternjavascript) sample code for the singleton pattern:

```
  return {
    getInstance: function () {

      if ( !instance ) {
        instance = init();
      }

      return instance;
    }
  };
```

The singleton pattern simply ensures that a new instance of the `$http` service itself doesn't get initiliazed over and over again... But it **doesn't** mean there is just one `XHR` object.

The pseudo-code for the `$http` service would look something like this:

```
var $httpProvider = (function() {
  var somePrivateConfig = "something important";

  var service = {
    request: function() {
      // make an HTTP request with an XHR object
    }
  };

  return {
    init: function() {
      // this is the important part that makes sure its a singleton
      window.$http = window.$http || service;
    }
  };

})();

/**
 * Something like this would be called whenever you
 * inject the $http service as a dependency... 
 * However, since it could be passed into multiple things all in the same runtime,
 * like controllers, directives, etc., we only need to initialize it ONE time
 */
$httpProvider.init();

/**
 * Now let's pretend we're inside, say, a controller.
 *
 * This method can safely be called many times,
 * but the method is always being called from the same singleton object
 */
$http.request();
```

Also, you'll notice that there's a local variable `somePrivateConfig` within the `$httpProvider` IIFE. If we were to re-initialize a new `$http` every time its injected to a component (whether that's a controller, directive, or whatever), a new private variable would be created, but we always want to be referencing that same value throughout the lifecycle of the `$http` object, so that we can guarantee that all those components are always referencing the same information.

But this has nothing to do with the `XHR` object itself. I may have misused some of the terminology above and misrepresented where and how providers themselves within the context of AngularJS are initialized into singleton objects, but the principle of the singleton pattern still stands in that it simply means the async request wrapper "class" (which is the `$http` service) is a singleton, but the `XHR` isn't.

Answer (score 0):

$http requests are async and return a promise with methods success() and error(). Below more information ($q service, which is an implementation of promises by Angularjs):

"A service that helps you run functions asynchronously, and use their return values (or exceptions) when they are done processing"

Read here:

- https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http
- https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q